# find the end of the body tag in an html file with python

Tags: python

Hi I have the following code

```
inex = "app/index.html" 
original = open(index,"r")
for line in original:
    if line =='</body>':
        print "here"
original.close()
```

but It doesn't seem to find the line '. Do I have to strip out potential white space even though the index.html file has none? Any clues on how to find the  tag?
Thanks

Comment: there are libs for parsing HTML, e.g. BeautifulSoap.

Comment: `if line.strip() == '</body>':`  But you really should be using an HTML parser.

Comment: @gefei +1 - HTML is a solved problem - use a tool designed for the job.

Comment: Any advantages to the HTML parser vs line.strip() ?

Answer (score 1):

Or you may try:

```
if '</body>' in line:
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you require that the line be exactly `"</body>"`, no whitespace. Also valid HTML could have other stuff before body as html just treats line endings as whitespace, ie you could have `foo</body>`

The most direct way to solve your problem is to simply read the files contents into a string and then call find on that string

```
allText = original.read()
location = allText.find("</body>")
```

There's also numerous HTML parsers out there that can do this work for you.